# Distinguish at runtime between an Eigen Array and an Eigen Matrix

Tags: eigen3

Is there a way to distinguish at runtime between an Eigen Array and an Eigen Matrix? For example,

```
template<typename Derived>
void foo( Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>& base )
{
if( /* base is an Eigen::Matrix */ )
{
   // do something
}
else // base is an Eigen::Array
{
   // do something else
}
}
```

I could write the function with two different signatures, e.g.

```
template<typename Derived>
void foo( Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& base )
{
}
```

and

```
template<typename Derived>
void foo( Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& base )
{
}
```

Having just one function would help avoid clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using `std::is_base_of` if `Derived` inherits from `MatrixBase` or `ArrayBase`:

```
template <typename Derived>
void foo(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> const&  base) {
    if (std::is_base_of<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>, Derived>::value) {
        fooMatrix();
    } else if (std::is_base_of<Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>, Derived>::value) {
        fooArray();
    }
}
```

With C++17 or later you can use an `if constexpr` branch for that (and use `std::is_base_of_v` for brevity). This allows to write code into the branches which would not compile with the opposite type.

```
template <typename Derived>
void foo(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> const&  base) {
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>, Derived>) {
        fooMatrix();
    } else if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>, Derived>) {
        fooArray();
    }
}
```

The second method is guaranteed to be checked at compile-time, the first one is not (but an optimizing compiler will still only produce code for the true-branch).

Comment: Thanks. I tried your second suggestion and it worked well.